# php sum column based on year criteria

Tags: php

I'm trying to sum a column named "total_fee" where the payment date is equaled to the current year but I received a blank. The code works with no error but the query came up empty. The payment_date is a datetime/timestamp. Does anyone know the php statement to sum current year and last year total? I have tried various ways with no lucks.

```
$stmt2 = $DB_CON_C->prepare("SELECT SUM(total_fee) AS current_year
                             FROM `".$row['email']."`
                             WHERE payment_date = date('Y')");
$stmt2->execute();
$sum2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<td>' .$sum2['current_year'].'</td>'
```

Comment: You have a table for every email address? You are misusing prepared statements, bind `date('Y')` (because that is suppose to be the PHP value, right?).

Comment: Yes, I have a table for every email address since each email is a separate account. It's easy for housekeeping to keep every account separate. Regarding your question, do I need to bind date('Y') because it's a php value, like let say "now()"? If it's not so, how do I bind a date('Y') when it's not a user variable?

Comment: That is really not how RELDBMS work - or should work. You really need to redo the DB-design. That is an insanely stupid design, since it automatically makes doing the "relations" bit extremely complicated. You have ONE table, "clients", and then you join that table with other tables to get different information.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Yes, I do have a master table containing clients data. I just wanted to name other tables that I have in the database according to the email address. My site is not a social website so I don't have hundred  thousand of tables naming after email addresses. In the end, it's all depend on what work for you depending on the context of your business.

Comment: No. The design is still horrible. You name the table something useful, like "client_accounts", "client_emails", "client_files" and so on. And you link them with IDs. Using an email-address as a table-name is... wow. Yes, horrible springs to mind.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie But I do have other tables with name like accounts, client _files, etc.

Comment: The point is, it should never be necessary to have a separate table for one specific client - that means that either your DB-design is wrong, or you're doing something else wrong. Depending on what information you have in this specific table, it is (again) probably not a good way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Nothing is absolute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the date value, not a php expression for the date.
You are also using prepared statements incorrectly.  Look here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

An easy way to test your query is to use 'between'

```
... WHERE payment_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: I understand that the prepared statement that I'm using is incorrect and would not be a preferred method. Would this way possess a security issue? Also, the reason I would like to use some kind of expression php to indicate the current year is because I want it to be dynamic so that I don't have to update the code for 2018.  Is there a way?

Comment: There sure is.  Make a date variable before the statement.   Like $firstDate = date('Y')  $secondDate= (whatever value) then in you bind this value to your prepared statement ....WHERE payment_date BETWEEN ? and ?;  Binding by bind_param("ss", $firstDate, $secondDate); ..... read the example link I provided above, all you need is there.